# What does 'a kind of private charter' signify, for the 1st Amendment (US Constitution)?

Tags: first-amendment

Original: Dworkin. *A Matter of Principle*. [p. 385 Top](https://books.google.com/books?id=LahVSmS26YEC&lpg=PA385&ots=WqZF1wTeed&dq=%22a%20kind%20of%20private%20charter%22&pg=PA385#v=onepage&q&f=false).
First Sighted: *Legal Writing in Plain English* (2nd edn, 2013). [p. 85 Top](https://books.google.com/books?id=PN_8vUWwXp0C&lpg=PA70&ots=dM4QMkEWMn&dq=%22a%20kind%20of%20private%20charter%22&pg=PA70#v=onepage&q=%22a%20kind%20of%20private%20charter%22&f=false).

> But there is not much attempt at analysis of the philosophical grounds of 
>   free speech or freedom of the press, or much effort to find the limits of the 
>   freedoms and powers Hentoff wants to defend. In this respect he is typical 
>   of journalists who complain about the fate of the First Amendment in the 
>   courts, though he writes better and with more enthusiasm and knowledge 
>   than most. The press takes the Amendment as a kind of **private charter [bold mine]**, and 
>   attacks more or less automatically every refusal of the courts to find some 
>   further protection in that charter. The newspapers and networks de- 
>   nounced the decisions in the *Farber* and *Herbert* cases as fiercely—indeed 
>   even more fiercely—than those in the cases of *The Progressive* and *Snepp*.

1. Am I correct that [charter](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=charter) signifies the following?

> [A written grant by the sovereign or legislative power of a country, by which a body such as a borough, company, or university is created or its rights and privileges defined.](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/charter)

2. I don't understand why the press'd regard it so, when they have in-house lawyers who'd disadvise them so?

Comment: "First slighted"? Also, definition 1.2 from your last link says "with modifier (in the UK) a written statement of the rights of a specified group of people". The First Amendment is a statement of a right of a group of people, so in that sense it could be considered a charter.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Am I correct that charter signifies the following?

Yes

> 2. I don't understand why the press'd regard it so, when they have in-house lawyers who'd disadvise them so?

This is a literary technique: the author and the press *know* it isn't a private charter but the press *would like it to be one* and that it should be interpreted in such a way that it enables them to do what they want it to do. The press are lobbying for their interpretation - not the actual interpretation.